# Mediawiki link search

Tags: mediawiki

I recently changed my mediawiki domain and everything is work well, but there are some pages that have links in them that point to resources on the discontinued domain. I could go through all the links and find them and change them but I was hoping that there was a way to search the pages themselves for the links so that I can avoid a lengthy search.

Comment: you should check database structure of mediawiki; find those articles and do update on articles which mach some string and replace it with something else. That is general idea; for more details you would need to provide database table names; structure of tables and sample records now; and how would you like them to look after update.

Answer (score 0):

The [Replace Text](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text) extension will provide you a nice web interface to do this (but remember to set up the job queue cronjob).

However, please don't reintroduce hardcoded domains again; instead, user the appropriate "magic words" (variables and functions) like [{{SERVER}}](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Technical_metadata) and {{fullurl:}}.